# How to plot 3D time series in R with lagged version

Tags: r, 3d, time-series

Im pretty new here, so im not really familiar with most commands.
I want to create 3D plot with my data on x axis, its lagged series in z, and time variable in y. Im using plotly at the moment but its giving me weird results. Is there any error in my codes, or am I just using the wrong package?
My data is export from 1997m01 to 2018m08.

Here is my code so far.

```
library(readxl)

Export <- read_excel("C:/Users/Alecsandra/Downloads/Export.xlsx")
export <- ts(Export, start=c(1997, 1), end=c(2018, 8), frequency=12)    
export1 <- ts(export[-1], start=c(1997, 1), end=c(2018, 7), frequency=12)

#Plotly said Z variable needs to be matrix so i made my time variable matrix
Time <- matrix(ncol=10, nrow=26) 
Time[] <- seq(1, 260, by = 1)

plot_ly(x = export1, y = export, z = Time) %>% add_surface()
```

Here is my result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to do, but maybe this is a hint, even if not a ts object:

```
library(rgl)
t <- seq(100)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(length(t))
y  <- lag(x)
plot3d(x,y,t)
lines3d(x,y,t, new=T, col=colorRampPalette(c("red", "grey80","blue"))(100)[t])
```

Basically look into the rgl package and plot3d etc.